# How to create multiple type of classes using onlineshop framework for abstract product in Pimcore

Tags: php, pimcore

I have created a product class in pimcore and is able to use \OnlineShop\Framework\Model\AbstractProduct as the parent class. And it is working fine. But I'm not able to create another class and use this onlineshop framework as parent.

Is it possible to create multiple product class in Pimcore ?

Answer (score 0):

As the docs say:

1. Extend AbstractProduct OR
2. Implements \OnlineShop\Framework\Model\IIndexable or \OnlineShop\Framework\Model\ICheckoutable or both in your custom Classes.

Besides that, for the category, there can only be one Class.